# Fredholm integral equations

Tags: integral-equations

I'm having problem obtaining the solution of the homogeneous Fredholm integral equation of the 2nd kind with a separable kernel. I always get a zero if I use the normal method I was taught for the non homogeneous type.

I have an example: y(x) = $\lambda \int_{-1}^{1}(x+z)\,y(z)dz$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1177932/homogeneous-fredholm-integral-equation/1178079#1178079

Answer (score 1):

It is rather simple, as soon as one guesses that the solution is a linear function:
$$y(x)= a_0 + a_1x$$
then placing all the terms of the equation into the left-hand side one finds there the following expression:

$$y(x)-\lambda x\int_{-1}^1 y(z)\mathrm dz 
      -\lambda  \int_{-1}^1 z y(z)\mathrm dz=a_0 + a_1 x - \frac{2}{3}a_1 \lambda - 2 a_0 x \lambda.$$

Which is, evidently, only equal to zero, if all coefficients
are equal to zero, so
$$ \left\{\begin{array}{ccccc}a_0&-&\frac{2}{3}a_1\lambda&=&0\\
-2a_0\lambda&+&a_1&=&0.\end{array}\right.$$
This system has only trivial solutions except when the determinant is equal to 0.
The determinant is $\Delta=1\times1-(-2\lambda)(-\frac{2}{3}\lambda)=1-\frac{4}{3}\lambda^2$. The non trivial solutions are obtained for $\lambda=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}{2}$ and in this case are given by $a_1=a_0\sqrt{3}$ or
$a_1=-a_0\sqrt3$.

That is the non-trivial solution you are looking for. The $\lambda$ values $\sqrt3/2$ and $\sqrt3/2$ are the corresponding eigenvalues.

Further, choosing

$$y(x)= a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3 + a_4x^4 + a_5x^5$$
and using the same calculations one can make sure that the higher degrees do not interfere.

Have fun!